# sql subqueries to mongodb

Tags: mysql, sql, mongodb

I am new to MongoDB and I am trying to turn SQL queries into MongoDB queries. But can't seem to find any way to turn a SQL query with a subquery to mongoDB.
for example:

`SELECT article, dealer, price
 FROM   shop
 WHERE  price=(SELECT MAX(price) FROM shop);`

I tried the following, but it doesn't seem to work.

```
db.shop.group({
"initial": {},
"reduce": function(obj, prev) {
    prev.maximumvalueprice = isNaN(prev.maximumvalueprice) ? obj.price : 
    Math.max(prev.maximumvalueprice, obj.price);
}}).forEach(
function(data){
    db.shop.find({
         "price": data
         }, 
        {
            "article": 1,
            "dealer": 1,
            "price": 1
        })
})
```

How do I convert this SQL query into a MongoDB query?

Comment: I have tried to fetch the max price with mongoDB group() function and then using the list it returns tried to use normal find() function. But it's not working. I seem to be doing some mistake somewhere.

Comment: do not forget to mark an answer or your (if the right answer wasn't provided), because in other way this question will be useless in future.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using MongoDB v. 3.2 or newer you can try to use `$lookup`.

Try to use aggregation:

- [$sort](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sort/) your collection by price by `DESC`;
- set [$limit](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/limit/) to 1 (it will take a first document, which will be with biggest price);
- then use [$lookup](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) to select the documents from the same collection by max price and set it to `tmpCollection` element;
- [$unwind](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) `tmpCollection`;
- [$replaceRoot](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/replaceRoot/)  - change document root to `$tmpCollection`

Example:

```
db.getCollection("shop").aggregate([
    {$sort: {"price":-1}},
    {$limit: 1},
    {$lookup: {
        from: "shop",
        localField: "price",
        foreignField: "price",
        as: "tmpCollection"
    }},
    {$unwind: "$tmpCollection"},
    {$replaceRoot: {newRoot:"$tmpCollection"}}
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need the aggregation framework for this task using **[`$first`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/first/)** within a **[`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#pipe._S_group)** pipeline stage on ordered documents. The initial pipeline step for ordering the documents in the collection is **[`$sort`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sort/#pipe._S_sort)**:

```
db.shop.aggregate([
    { "$sort": { "price": -1 } }, // <-- sort the documents first in descending order
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": null,
            "article": { "$first": "$article" }, 
            "dealer": { "$first": "$dealer" },
            "price": { "$first": "$price" }
        }
    }
])
```

or using **[`$last`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/last/#grp._S_last)**

```
db.shop.aggregate([
    { "$sort": { "price": 1 } }, // <-- note the sort direction
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": null,
            "article": { "$last": "$article" },
            "dealer": { "$last": "$dealer" },
            "price": { "$last": "$price" }
        }
    }
])
```

Comment: Thanks......I was trying to do it using aggregate() first, but didn't think of sorting to get the job done. Nice idea!! Again thanks.